# How can you filter out columns in a DataFrame which all have the same values - for example, all categorical variables giving either Yes or No

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a large DataFrame which has multiple categorical variables which return either Yes or No. I want to filter out these specific categorical variables.

I've used this code to no avail:

```
#Seperating the Yes/No categorical variables
df_yn = [var for var in df.columns if df[var].unique() == pd.array(['Yes', 'No'])]

#As well as this:

#Seperating the Yes/No categorical variables
df_yn = [var for var in df.columns if df[var].unique() == (['Yes', 'No'])]
```

I tried running just one column with this:

```
df['PhoneService'].unique() == pd.array(['Yes', 'No'])
```

and I get this:

```
<BooleanArray>
[False, False]
Length: 2, dtype: boolean
```

Quick Update: Tried this, also doesn't work.

```
#Seperating the Yes/No categorical variables
temp = df['PhoneService'].unique()
df_yn = [var for var in df.columns if df[var].unique() == temp]

#output:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you find out your comparison returned an array with 2 booleans. You could use `all(...)` to check all the values in that array are `True`. But what if your compared arrays are not in the same order? Or you have more unique values than planned?

```
>>> all(pd.array(['Yes', 'No']) == pd.array(['Yes', 'No']))
True
>>> all(pd.array(['Yes', 'No']) == pd.array(['No', 'Yes']))
False
>>> all(pd.array(['Yes', 'No']) == pd.array(['Yes', 'No', 'Foo']))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 65, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 29, in __eq__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/string_.py", line 351, in _cmp_method
    mask = isna(self) | isna(other)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

There’s a “pure pandas” way that could use [`pd.array.equals()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.equals.html) but that still doesn’t solve sorting:

```
>>> pd.array(['Yes', 'No']).equals(pd.array(['Yes', 'No']))
True
>>> pd.array(['Yes', 'No']).equals(pd.array(['No', 'Yes']))
False
>>> pd.array(['Yes', 'No']).equals(pd.array(['Yes', 'No', 'Foo']))
False
```

Since `unique` doesn’t sort for you, just make sure to use a sorted array as your basis for comparison.

```
>>> pd.array(['No', 'Yes']).equals(pd.array(sorted(df['PhoneService'].unique())))
True
```

That’s rather tedious, so we can use a number of numpy utility functions, depending on what you find most explicit:

```
>>> np.array_equal(['No', 'Yes'], sorted(df['PhoneService'].unique()))
True
>>> np.setdiff1d(['No', 'Yes'], df['PhoneService'].unique()).size == 0
True
```

Alternately you can do the comparison on all the elements and aggregate the resulting boolean series:

```
>>> df['PhoneService'].isin(['No', 'Yes']).all()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't be very performant for large dataframes as it applies the lambda function to all values in the DF.  However, as a starter for ten, here's one option:

```
# Create dummy data – two columns with a mix of values, two with the same value
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], 10),
    'b': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], 10),
    'c': ['Yes'] * 10,
    'd': ['No'] * 10,
})

>>> df
    a   b   c   d
0   Yes Yes Yes No
1   No  Yes Yes No
2   No  No  Yes No
3   No  No  Yes No
4   Yes Yes Yes No
5   Yes No  Yes No
6   Yes Yes Yes No
7   Yes Yes Yes No
8   Yes No  Yes No
9   No  No  Yes No

# Convert dataframe to ints
int_df = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Yes' else 0)

# Compute the variance of each column and use those with variance > 0 to filter the columns of the original dataframe
>>> df[int_df.var()[int_df.var() > 0].index]
    a   b
0   Yes Yes
1   No  Yes
2   No  No
3   No  No
4   Yes Yes
5   Yes No
6   Yes Yes
7   Yes Yes
8   Yes No
9   No  No
```